# what is difference between [ data$group == c("A","B")] and [ data$group == "A" | data$group == "B" ]?

Tags: r, select, subset

I found sth different between these two functions but I don't know why they are different.

It'd be thankful if someone who know a reason about that leave some comments

Here's a problem

for exemple,

`data$group` has 16 `chr` of "`A`" and 16 `chr` of "`B`"

if I'm using a function `c()`,

```
d1 <- subset(data, data$group == c("A","B"))
```

`d1` has just some part of total number like 12

but if I'm using another one,

```
d2 <- subset(data, data$group == "A" | data$group == "B")
```

`d2` has same number of data

what makes those two things difference?

Comment: In `d1` instead of `==`, you may need to use `%in%`...?

Comment: %in% worked out, Thank you. And could you tell me why is  not "==" working? I thought like it means data$group == "A" or data$group == "B" (like extract row  has "A" or "B" in data$group)

Comment: `data$group == "A"` or `data$group == "B"` is `%in%` not `==`. If you want more description, I can add some details below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is how your data looks like:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  group = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 16, TRUE)
)
data
#>    group
#> 1      A
#> 2      B
#> 3      A
#> 4      A
#> 5      B
#> 6      B
#> 7      B
#> 8      A
#> 9      A
#> 10     A
#> 11     B
#> 12     A
#> 13     A
#> 14     A
#> 15     A
#> 16     A

subset(data, data$group == c("A","B"))
#>    group
#> 1      A
#> 2      B
#> 3      A
#> 6      B
#> 9      A
#> 13     A
#> 15     A
```

What happens: `==()` replicates the vector `c("A","B")`until it
matches the length of `data$group`.

This illustrates the result of
`subset(data, data$group == c("A","B"))`:

```r
data.frame(
  group = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 16, TRUE),
  AB    = rep(c("A", "B"), 8),
  match = data$group == rep(c("A", "B"), 8)
)
#>    group AB match
#> 1      A  A  TRUE
#> 2      B  B  TRUE
#> 3      B  A  TRUE
#> 4      B  B FALSE
#> 5      B  A FALSE
#> 6      B  B  TRUE
#> 7      A  A FALSE
#> 8      B  B FALSE
#> 9      A  A  TRUE
#> 10     B  B FALSE
#> 11     A  A FALSE
#> 12     B  B FALSE
#> 13     A  A  TRUE
#> 14     A  B FALSE
#> 15     A  A  TRUE
#> 16     A  B FALSE
```

The `match` column shows which rows are TRUE and the row numbes match
the indices of `subset(data, data$group == c("A","B"))`.
`d2 <- subset(data, data$group == "A" | data$group == "B")` the other hand
compares each row of `data$group` with A **or** B. And that is true for
all values in the vector.

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>